# ¿Cómo crear cron job en php?

Tags: php

nesesito crear una tarea programada que ejecute una función vez al día en php.
**Ejemplo: insertar un registro todo los días a las 23:00:00**

```php
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("70.161.273.17","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (ID,TEXTO,VALOR) VALUES ('1','datos','50')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
```

el proyecto lo tengo en un hosting, no en localhost ¿hay alguna manera de crear esa tarea programada en php?

Comment: tenes acceso ssh?

Comment: he ocupado $salida = shell_exec('ls -l'); echo $salida; y me retorna drwx---r-x 9 k24e1619 inetuser    4096 May  2 12:50 assets, mas otros archivos como este

Comment: tener acceso ssh = si en tu terminal pones `ssh tunombredeusuario@ipdetuserverenelehosting` te pide contraseña y hace login ?

Comment: como alternativa si tenés acceso al mysql y permisos de setear globals, activas el scheduler con `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` y luego creas un evento onda `CREATE EVENT ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-05-02 23:00:00' DO ...ELSQL...`.